# What is the posterior distribution $p(\textbf{f} | \textbf{y})$ for a Gaussian Process regression?

Tags: machine-learning, gaussian-process, prior, posterior

What is the posterior distribution $p(\textbf{f} | \textbf{y})$ for a Gaussian Process regression?

Suppose that $p(y_n |x_n, f) = N(f(x_n), \sigma^2)$ with prior on $\textbf{f} = [f(x_1), \ldots f(x_n)]^T$ as $p(\textbf{f}) = N(0, K)$ where $K = K(X, X)$ is the $n\times n$ Kernel matrix. How can I derive the expression for the posterior $f(\textbf{f} | \textbf{y})$?

It is not clear to me whether the posterior is again going to be a Gaussian Process or it is going to be a Gaussian. Please help.

Note: I am not asking about predictive posterior which every books seem to discuss. None of the books even mention the posterior I am looking for

Comment: Yes the posterior will be Gaussian, and you can use a combination of Bayes theorem and completing the square to show this.

Comment: @microhaus These notes say otherwise, Slide 4/6 http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/teaching/4f13/1920/gp%20and%20data.pdf

Comment: Unless there is something I have missed, I am unable to understand how on slide 4/6, "Gaussian process prior with zero mean and covariance function $k$ and likelihood [in slides] *leads to a Gaussian process posterior*" amounts to saying otherwise?

Comment: Also, the predictive posterior that every book seems to discuss and the posterior you are looking for are the same. It is simply the conditional Gaussian distribution where $y_1,...,y_n$ are fixed at $x_1,...,x_n$ and we find posterior distribution (or conditional distribution) at any new $x_i, x_j, ...$.